# Is there a way to Symbolicate Xcode Energy Reports?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, symbolicate

Apple released a [2018 WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/228/) titled `What's New in Energy Debugging` where they go into using a new future of Xcode: Energy Reports.
In the video they show an already symbolicated energy report.

When I attempt to right click and select "Symbolicate" I receive the following error.

[image: Symbolicate Error]

Is there a way to symbolicate an energy report from a build that was not archived using Xcode (was archived using a build chain using command line tools)? I have access to the dSYM and archive.

Comment: Well, the usual thing when you need to symbolicatw something for which there is no archive is to archive it now. Surely it corresponds to some git commit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @matt. I have the archive and the dSYM file (both created from the build chain).

Comment: You said “from a build that was not archived”.

Comment: I see the confusion. "from a build that was not archived using Xcode" but I have the archive from the build chain. Will update question. Good spot @matt

Comment: @DanielStorm, if you have report itself and it has frames info, and there are dSYM, then you can symbolicate it (or part of it) manually using `atos` command line tool. Of course it is possible also to write a script to automate.